# How can I convert the Device Path to Win32 Path in Golang?

Tags: windows, winapi

For example, I have this device path: `\\Device\\HarddiskVolume3\\` and I want to convert it into `C:\\` or something similar (`D:\\` or `E:\\`, etc.).

I have an idea to implement it in Golang, but it seems like it is not optimized at all:

1. List all the current driver in the machine (eg. **C:\, D:\, E:\, F:\, etc.**)
2. Convert it into **Device Path** using [**QueryDosDevice**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-querydosdevicew), and save them in a list
3. When I receive a **Device Path**, loop through the list and take the **Win32 path** that equal to the **Device Path** that I convert before.

Can anyone suggest a better idea?

Comment: You're thinking in a correct direction, the step 1 is not necessary: `QueryDosDevice` is able to return all defined "DOS devices" present in the system. Please note that your question has nothing to do with programming in Go.

Comment: [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/displaying-volume-paths) from MSDN hints at that `GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW` called on your device name _may_ work directly and return a DOS device attached to it, if any. I would try that first.